# Battery life greatly depreciated in 64-bit when compared to 32-bit

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, battery

I have a Dell E6400 and have been using Ubuntu on this machine for just over a year. Previously I used 9.10 on 32bit. When I upgraded to use 10.04 I remained on 32bit and battery life seemed just fine. I changed to 64-bit and since then I get the "battery life is old" notification and the battery just doesnt last more than 20mins even with a full charge.

How would I tell which application is draining off the battery? Also is this a known issue?

Answer (score 4):

try installing powerTOP. Its an application by Intel, that analyses the syste,

open a terminal from Applicaions > Accessories > Terminal.

type in the following on the prompt:

`sudo apt-get install powertop`

enter your login password, and run it by typing 
`sudo powertop` in the terminal after it installs, since it need to run as root. It will show you what things are squeezing your CPU.

Comment: Thank you! I can see that nviewer.bin is using most of the CPU, this would be the firefox flashplayer   

 Top causes for wakeups:
  22.5% (138.5)   npviewer.bin
  14.9% ( 91.7)   [extra timer interrupt]
  13.1% ( 80.7)   [kernel scheduler] Load balancing tick
  12.4% ( 76.3)   [ohci1394, eth1] <interrupt>
  10.5% ( 64.7)   [i915] <interrupt>
   7.2% ( 44.5)D  firefox-bin

What would be the next be course of action?

Comment: it seems that the stats are normal, there isnt any problem with those numbers. I guess the problem lies in the way ubuntu is using the processor. I am googling as we type, it should come up with something.

Comment: take a look at http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-latitude-vostro-precision/431561-dissapearing-battery-charge-e6400.html It seems that this particular model has some issues with the battery, and misreports the current charge.

Comment: I would have agreed but then the battery itself has a little 5-led display on it which you press a button to see charge level. This too seems to deplete at the same rate.

Comment: oops, and u are using it since "just" over a year, which makes u ineligible for warranty, unless u had the extended cover. Try to get the battery changed. Does this happen with 64-bit windows, or 64-bit fedora?

Comment: take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks