# Does a HDD run more in Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, temperature

This is something that's been bothering me, and I would like to know if it's an issue that's known. OK, I have monitored the HDD temperature, for a couple of days, when running in Ubuntu and Windows 7. I have both OS installed on the same laptop, and I'm using `Speedfan` to monitor the hdd temp in Windows 7, and `hddtemp` to monitor on Ubuntu.

When running on Windows 7 the HDD usually stay around 37-39. This is on the load of when just web browsing, watch movies, and programming. And when I do the same thing on Ubuntu the HDD will go to 40-42. Most of the time however it stay 41-42 degree. Btw, even when just idling in Ubuntu the HDD will go over 40 degrees.

This isn't a really big issue maybe since I read that HDD can handle temperature to at least 60 degree. However since the HDD is located just where I put my right palm, so it is quite disturbing at some times.

Is this temperature the same for you guys which are running Ubuntu 10.10 on a laptop?

Answer (score 2):

The hard disk temperature depends on the ambient temperature, so it is not easily comparable.

There are other discussions on askubuntu.com that talk about `powertop` which is a tool to control the fine issues of power tuning. Have a look at it (search) to see if you can perform some optimisations for your laptop.

The reason why Ubuntu might be a little warmer for the hard disk is due to how often it needs to access the disk. There is a system option called laptop_mode, which you can set and see what temperature the disk reaches when idle. To do so,

```
# Read the current value for laptop_mode
cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
# Set the laptop_mode to five, which reduces the accesses to the disk, letting it sleep more.
sudo echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
```

When the system lets the hard disk to sleep for a little when idle, the hard disk goes in a lower power mode, and becomes cooler. However, this change of power mode has a small effect on the lifetime of the disk. You can use `Disk Utility` in the Administrative tools to find out how often the disk goes into and comes back from the low power state.

Read more at
[Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

Comment: this is quite informative thanks. I'll have a look into that