# laptop-mode-tools and harddrive spinoff

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

So I wanted to extend my laptop battery life. After googleing a lot I found many tips and tricks. [Some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks) even in this site as well. Then I found this package in synaptic as well `laptop-mode-tools`. Now I am not well aware of what harddrive spinoffs are, so I have a dilemma of installing this package as it seems to remove acpi support as well. So my question is, how reliable is this package in battery life extension and what configurations should I use with it ? Also I stumbled upon some posts saying spinoffs may kill the harddrive as well. So can anyone clearify with some configuration tips especially for laptop-mode-tools.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I use laptop-mode-tools without any problem. I use it without any problem with ACPI besides it. Check this site:
[link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools)

Of course, this site is of ArchLinux so "pacman" command and "rc.conf" doesn't aplly to you.

Answer (score 0):

To my memory laptop-mode-tools is now "deprecated", and you really should not use it on a recent system.

Instead you could probably try `powertop`. Not nearly perfect, but it should do something to help out a bit ;).

Comment: I don't know if its deprecated. AFAIK it does have some hooks that are also used by pm-utils so it tends to conflict with the package but it has many more option than pm-utils. I use 'powertop' as well. But powertop doesnot run as daemon or automatically save power. It just says where power is being used and gives some settings advice. I would be happy if someone could recommend me some settings for not conflicting laptop-mode and pm-utils.

Comment: Are you sure it has been deprecated? I talked to a friend of mine [who is a DD](http://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=rrs%40debian.org) and he co-maintains laptop-mode-tools and he says that lmt is still under maintenance.

Comment: @Manish that's why I said "to my memory". I read somewhere (a while ago) that it isn't needed anymore, and shouldn't be installed unless absolutely needed or something.

Comment: @roland-taylor : It isn't installed by default in Ubuntu and many other distros anyway because AFAIK it does not have a GUI

Answer (score 0):

Regarding spinning down your HD: have a look at **hdparm**. Someone mentioned it in the thread you linked ( [Tips to extend battery life](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks/8078#8078) )

However, I never changed the settings myself. It does not require laptopmodetools