# Battery life is getting shorter and it longer to charge

Tags: power-management, battery

Just installed Ubuntu on my laptop. What is weird is that my battery life has become shorter, and when I try to charge it, it said that my battery will be full in 8:30 hrs. While on my Windows, it only take less than 2 hrs make it full.

Please help

Comment: If you have only just installed then you probably need to run ubuntu for a while, charging and discharging so that ubuntu can gather statistics about your battery life

Comment: You seem to be comparing one program's estimate at the beginning of charging with another program's estimate. How long does it **really** take to charge?

On your system, look at `/var/log/pm*.log`, and see if anything fails, look at the `pm-utils` package (`dpkg -L pm-utils`), and search AskUbuntu, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks

Comment: You also need to make sure you have the latest updates.  In terminal type: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**, or just use Update Manager.

Answer (score 1):

With the Update from Friday 09.12.2011 this problem should be solved.
I Had the sam eproblem and now my battery time is longer than 2 hours and loding is much faster.

I hope the update will help you ;-)