# How can I improve battery life on an Eeepc 1015 PEM?

Tags: battery, asus, eeepc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

I own an Asus Eee PC 1015 PEM. I've decided to fully shift to Ubuntu, I've been using it on other systems since the 5th release, so I'm very well familiarized with Ubuntu.

Even though I'm very happy with the OS, I've been noticing 2 things:
One is that my battery life is almost only half of what I got with Windows, the second is that most of the time the core temperature goes around 55º C.

I've installed jupiter, and added the "quiet splash pcie_aspm=force", I have also installed the scripts to slow down disk speeds when running on battery, and still I can't get more than 6 hours of battery life, while on Windows I used to get from 9 to 10 ours.

I want to know if there are is anything else that I can do to make my battery last longer and make my computer temperature come a little lower?

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu there a lot of background processes running all the time,this leads to battery consumption more than windows, what you can do is go to System Monitor and end all unwanted processes.

Answer (score 0):

i won't recommend jupiter. follow this instead: 
http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/HowTo/Configure
regarding cpu temperature mine is at 60 c with top peak at 67 c and that's not a problem at all.