# Are there power plans for Ubuntu like in Windows 7?

Tags: power-management

Please people anyone if can help me. I'm new to ubuntu, I mean have work with it since 11.04 come out. My only problem is battery life. In windows 7 I have balanced power saver and high performance is there anyway i can have these power plans on ubuntu 11.10?

Few weeks ago I saw someone post the same question and when I saw answers I found it but now I can't find it anywhere:( please help me i really wanna stay to ubuntu but I'm most of time travelling and battery life is so important for me.

Comment: Look at *"Related"* on the right side of this page to see if your question is there?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a question about battery life tips:

[Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

And here is an indicator to simply change battery consumption behaviour:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html

Comment: yesssssssssssssss exactly jupiter was what i was looking for thank you sir! thank you so much !!!