# Maximizing battery life in terminal only mode

Tags: command-line, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

A while ago talked to a buddy, who managed to enlengthen battery life a lot by shutting down graphics card, slowing down CPU etc. Ofc we we're talking about terminal only, when u dont need those things. For some time I try to recreate his setup, withous succes. Has anyone tried extreme battery life enlengthing? I would love to see some tips.