# How to enable laptop-mode?

Tags: laptop, battery

Laptop-mode is said to be one of the energy efficiency boosters for Linux. Now, [sources](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/packages/ubuntu) I found say that to activate it you need to:

1. Install `laptop-mode-tools`.
2. Append `LAPTOP_MODE_ENABLED=true` (if it doesn't exist; otherwise make sure that it's set to true) inside `/etc/default/acpi-support`.

However, even after doing this, laptop mode is not running (I have it set up in `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` to be always on):

```
~$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode 
0
```

Does anyone know **how can I enable laptop-mode?**

It is mentioned [here](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/packages/ubuntu) that the Ubuntu package is "crippled". Is it really the case that Ubuntu doesn't allow you to enter this mode on AC? If so, why?

**Edit: It seems that laptop-mode is not necessary any more since Ubuntu 12.04, according to [Is "laptop-mode-tools" still relevant for 12.04 and the 3.x kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172391/is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-for-12-04-and-the-3-x-kernels)**

Comment: I have laptop mode enabled on my system though

Comment: Laptop mode magically started working without me changing anything, so I guess the above steps are sufficient. I must have not rebooted enough times (or I maybe just did a log off - log on and that isn't enough).

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172391/is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-for-12-04-and-the-3-x-kernels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The steps listed in the question are correct, the only thing remaining is to reboot your machine (possibly a couple of times). After that laptop mode will be enabled:

```
~$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode 
2
```

Once laptop-mode is working, you can follow these steps to configure laptop-mode...

Edit `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` and change

```
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=0
```

to

```
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1
```

Also check for the battery mode on battery state and turn it on if it is off by changing the value to `1`

e.g.:   `ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_BATTERY = 1`

*You can set many other option in this config file (the file has many self-explanatory comments). You should try setting them to your liking.*

When you're done, restart laptop-mode with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/laptop-mode restart
```

P.S. If laptop-mode is still not on after rebooting the machine, you can try playing with this command as well to manually enable it:

Check that it's active on AC with for example:

```
$ sudo laptop_mode start
```

which should output:

```
Laptop mode 
enabled, 
active [unchanged]
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for the tips about configuring laptop-mode. I also picked those settings in laptop-mode.conf. Just take care to have the `LAPTOP_MODE_ENABLED=true` inside /etc/deffault/acpi-support so that you don't have to turn it on manually every time - it seems this does work in the end.

Comment: please what line is this setting on inside the acpi-support file?

Comment: I appended it to the end of the file, because it didn't exist in my acpi-support file. Take a look at the original question, I edited it to be more clear.

Comment: Why did you change powersave mode on in AC by `ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1`? I am thinking it here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307646/16920 where I need power in computations, especially when I am in AC.

Answer (score 3):

enter root by

```
sudo su
```

and then

```
echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
```

If you want more tips to save power check out [LessWatts](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403120659/https://lesswatts.org/). I was able to extend my battery life from 2 hours to 3 and a half.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though I think echoing to /proc is a temporary solution - one would have to repeat it after every system boot. See my comment to the original question, I got the acpi config file method working after all.

Comment: nope. when you do it as root, it sets it permanently.

Comment: OK, well then this is another method of doing it.

Comment: Add line like `vm.laptop_mode=5` under `/etc/sysctl.d` to have it applied every boot.

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu Menu choose Preferences -> Default applications for LXSession -> Settings -> Laptop mode -> yes

Comment: What does this actually do?

Comment: I don't know. With a quick search I got the impression that it might be related to TLP or Laptop mode tools: 

"14.  Tweaks For Ubuntu Power Management
...

Apart from these tips, you can follow to install TLP, which helps to keep the laptop cool and safe.
...
You can also Install Laptop Mode Tools, which helps to reduce power consumption by slowing down Hard disk speed and kernel control. To install it run the following command…

sudo ..."

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking at this in 2024 or beyond should probably be aware of TLP, which is a modern alternative to laptop-mode-tools.  Laptop-mode-tools still exists, but I personally like TLP.

The need for either may be less than it used to be with good CPU scaling support in kernels, but if you have neither you are still potentially leaving power savings on the table while on battery mode.

While TLP is very tuneable, its defaults are conservative, reliable and will aim to get the best power reduction it can in laptop mode without noticeably affecting the feeling of performance at all.

You can further reduce power usage by editing its config file, though you should probably consult documentation while doing so.

Anyway I thought it was worth a mention.