# How can I save my laptops battery from draining?

Tags: 12.04, performance, brightness, monitor, battery

I am using ubuntu 12.04 (switched from windows 8 recently) and I am finding that this OS is draining my laptops battery like anything (works only like 70% of windows).
I also found this interesting quote from wikipedia:

*Ubuntu 10.04 LTS has also been criticized for its poor battery life on Laptops and Netbooks, even as OEM on devices such as Asus's eeePC, when compared to Microsoft Windows 7, with Ubuntu having been shown to use between 14–56% more power.[122] Ubuntu's developers have acknowledged and sought to solve the issues of power consumption in the 12.04 LTS release.*

Can ubuntu experts suggest me some tips and tricks to save my battery life ?

Also tell me how can I monitor my battery usage, like which application/process is more resource(power) consumptive ? Is there any way we can select system performance schemes like we do in Windows like *High Performance* or *Battery Saver* types ?

I also see a problem with my ubuntu display brightness setting. I manually set it to lowest possible but ubuntu forgets my setting everytime I reboot my machine. Is there any way we can permanently save this setting and ubuntu can remember it ?

Comment: This has been asked several times on AU... http://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks

Comment: Now a days most laptops comes with dual grpahics/ hybrid gpu/ optimus configuration. If you don't install correct drivers, correct work around both GPU will be on and will drain battery

Comment: Brightness issue may be fixed by installing correct drivers. to get more help, post result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: @Web-E : avimehenwal@AviMehenwal-DYNAC:~$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series]

Comment: @Web-E Just checked from 'Additional Drivers' that I am using "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX Graphics driver" on my laptop. Does this driver also creates concern ?

Comment: No. Your laptop doesn't have dual GPU. See the duplicate link.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 2):

Well for the brightness you should look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart). You can't make Ubuntu remember your brightness settings but it will always boot with a predefined brightness level.

For the battery life you have to activate `laptop-mode`. It might not be active by default. To check on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180712/how-to-enable-laptop-mode) is a link to a complete walk through.

For the high performance and such power schema you can download `Jupiter`. You can copy and paste the following commands in a command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

EDIT: Also [Web-E](https://askubuntu.com/users/35775/web-e) has a great point, you should check if you have two graphic cards (i.e. nVidia Optimus technology - most modern laptops have this technology). If you do, you can install [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) and then you can run every graphic intensive application using the command `optirun` before it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very informative answer :)  But I dont have nVidia ! my laptop has ATI Graphic Card

Comment: and @Soroosh129 I cannot even edit file /etc/rc.local for brightness issue. It says "chmod: changing permissions of `rc.local': Operation not permitted" when I try to change the file permissions for editing.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use chmod.

Comment: avimehenwal@AviMehenwal-DYNAC:/etc$ ls -l | grep rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      306 Aug 18  2012 rc.local

Comment: you have the write permission as a root. try `sudo vi /etc/rc.local` and see how that goes. edit: sorry I keep forgetting that your user is root, my bad but doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I cant say it helped but I feel very grateful for your efforts. i cannot type in anything and alter file content using the above command. It doesn't understand my enter or arrow keys :(

Comment: yes you should press the `insert` button or `i` after entering `vi`. then you can enter text. after you're done press the escape button and type `:wq`.