# Overheating problem on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, cpu, overheating

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu to 13.04. Since this time I have overheating problems with CPU and graphic card. I also can't use fglrx drivers, because Ubuntu does not work properly, so I use the driver that was installed (Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD).

I have Intel Core i7 CPU Q 720 and mobility Radeon HD5730.

Comment: you should look this too http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not being able to install the gpu driver could be the issue, since it worked on the older version, it may be a kernel issue, have you tried booting the old kernel from your boot menu?
here is a [mainline kernel installer](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater/blob/master/README.md) you can use it to try different versions maybe a newer one will let you install the driver, if not maybe a older one will

Comment: Thanks. I haven't checked the driver yet, but the temperature is about ten degrees lower.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and `TLP` kind of helped reducing its amplitude (but my laptop still overheats from time to time... Guess things aren't that stable on 13.04 yet).

Here's how to install `tlp`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

And then just launch it (once, it's supposed to launch at startup after that):

```
sudo tlp start
```

[More information about tlp on webupd8.](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)

**EDIT:**

More info on how to configure `tlp` on this answer from [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681).

Answer (score 1):

I reduced overheating in Ubuntu 13.04 by [activating laptop-mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180712/how-to-enable-laptop-mode).