# How to get rid of overheating in Dell studio 1558 laptop installed with Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, dell, overheating, fan

I am using Dell Studio 1558 Laptop.
Installed with Ubuntu 12.10
It gets overheated many times and then system start to hang, 
how to get rid of this problem of overheating?
Either i should increase the speed of fan ,if yes then how?
if any other option then please suggest.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/286792/overheating-problem-on-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: What surface is the laptop on? If you have heat issues you should avoid using it on thermal insulators such as glass, and make sure you allow air to flow out of it by not using it on top of a pillow or something.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using Ubuntu 12.10 so you can install Jupiter in it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Once installed use it in power saving mode.

More information and complete tutorial: [Solve Overheating Issue In Ubuntu 12.10](http://itsfoss.com/solve-overheating-issue-in-ubuntu-12-10/)