# Have PM utils power.d scripts run all the time

Tags: power-management, pm-utils

The pm util power saving scripts only work when a laptop is on battery, not when it is plugged in to AC. Is there a way to make pm utils run all the time, regardless of whether the laptop is connected to a power outlet or not?

Comment: just read full description on my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: check working with tlp Apply Battery Settings (ignoring the actual power source):

sudo tlp bat

Answer (score 3):

You can enabled this using:

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

or if you want, I guess you could add the following to /etc/rc.local:

```
pm-powersave true
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works temporarily, because if I unplug the power cord from my laptop and plug it in again, the power save mode becomes false again.

Comment: @Colin Ian King is my answer right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script

```
 sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/power
```

Copy paste the following the following in power file

```
#!/bin/sh

# Shell script to reduce energy consumption when running battery. Place
# it in /etc/pm/power.d/ and give execution rights.

if on_ac_power; then

# Start AC powered settings #

pm-powersave true

else

# Start battery powered settings -#

 pm-powersave true


 fi
```

Now you need to assign execution permission of power script

```
 sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/power
```

Now you will have pm-powersave true on both ac/bat

[How do I make Powertop changes permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent)