# Loud fan and very hot pc

Tags: power-management, battery, overheating, fan

I know, that you don't like when someone ask same question as is answered but I try a lot of solutions and nothing helped...

I installed Ubuntu 12.10, everything is good but fan is very noise and battery life decrease from about 3,5h to 1,2h. I tryed everything I found (Jupiter, powertop, to install drivers, switcheroo etc.) but nothing helped...

HP Probook 4530s
3,8 GiB
Intel Pentium CPU B950 @ 2.10 GHz x2
graphic- Intel Sandybridge Mobile
64-bit
another graphic card Radeon 6490M

sorry for my english

Comment: So after installing jupiter,did you change the performance option?
And also, have you tried `laptop-mode-tools`?

Comment: Fans are controlled by the bios. So the only possible explanation is that something is running in background. Do "sudo apt-get install powertop" and than "sudo powertop". So you can look what is taking CPU performance. (it would be an device i think)

Comment: @Soroosh129 Is `laptop-mode-tools` still relevant for 12.xx? Actual question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172391/is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-for-12-04-and-the-3-x-kernels) (no definitive answer though).

Comment: @pileofrocks Well it helped me to get a sky rocket battery performane! my Ubuntu 12.04 didn't care about USB suspension for example (but the link is really interesting though - thank you, I will check power.d) and all USB ports were always ON but I don't know if it is relevant in 12.10 but it's worth a shot I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a hardware problem. Could be the fan is not working well, so it needs to run on high, or could be the heat sink to the CPU was knocked loose.

Otherwise try `ps -ef` to see if there are any processes running that are causing your CPU to overheat.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the CPU frequency scaling is working properly. There are variety of ways to monitor that, but you can quickly check it by typing in the terminal:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i "cpu mhz"`

In idle or low load, the frequency of the threads should be lower than the maximum (in your case lower than 2100 MHz).

Comment: I tried, it shows me 2 cpu, both 800.000