# Is laptop-mode-tools still relevant on 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, laptop

Do they make some difference? I read in Ubuntu wiki that actually it has good power configuration management out of box.

Comment: Have a look please http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 4):

No. pm-powersave now takes care of that functionality.
The relevant files are:

```
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/pm-powersave.8.html

Also, see the comprehensive answer here:  [Is "laptop-mode-tools" still relevant for 12.04 and the 3.x kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172391)

Answer (score 0):

If you want further improvement to power consumption install TLP via its PPA from www.linrunner.de/tlp its far more effective and implements true power saving profile to your laptop.

Comment: Be careful with TLP, in my case it did something funky with the system and made it very slow. Also, I have not seen any objective tests showing that TLP is any better or worse then the default on Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have it in different laptops from AMD to latest Haswell CPU and AMD netbooks and never faced an issue. Also tests have been done by quite a few sites that have testified to TLP's effectiveness regarding power savings.