# Battery dies quickly in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

I am new to Ubuntu. I use Samsung laptop. The battery dies quickly while I am using Ubuntu 12.04. The charge holds good for hardly 1hr 45mins. On the contrary, I get 3hr 30min while using Windows OS.

I have tried reducing the brightness but it didn't effect much. Any ideas?

Comment: I also experience the same thing and from what I read, it's not a problem with Ubuntu per se but an issue which has apparently been resolved in the Linux Kernel 3.3 upwards.