# What about life battery in ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

I have a basic Notebook Samsung RV513 with Ati Vision AMD Graphics & chipset but I realized than ubuntu 12.04.1 drains my battery. I checked some forums and help but it said modifying my kernel and bla bla, looks hard to do any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing jupiter

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html

and running powertop and changing the tunables

```
sudo apt-get powertop
sudo powertop
```

https://lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/