# Battery drain and over heating

Tags: laptop, battery, heat

I recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and I have started to see a dramatic decrease in battery life. About 2 hours battery life on Ubuntu, as opposed to when I had Windows (about 5 hours).

What could I do to end this overheating and lengthen battery life?

I have a Samsung Series 7 Chronos i7 2.2ghz 1TB 6GB ram

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks

Comment: This is possible because graphics driver might not be installed..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Second, if you have an AMD video card, which drivers are you using? I have many experiences of AMD GPUs overheating when used with the open source drivers or the restricted drivers provided by Ubuntu. You may want to try out the drivers from the AMD website.

Also, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207733/why-does-my-laptop-with-amd-radeon-hd-76xx-graphics-get-overheated-when-using-ub) question out. It is about the HD76xx series, but may apply to others as well.

Finally, search askubuntu for "overheating", you may get many hits.

Regards,
Errikos

Answer (score 0):

Install hardware drivers, if using 12.04 LTS download latest one as it comes with 3.8 kernel and lastly install TLP from www.linrunner.de for power savings. My ASUS K55VM laptop matches Windows 8 consumption using Ubuntu 12.04.3