# Battery drains so fast

Tags: 12.04, laptop, power-management, battery

I have an HP laptop. It is a 64 bit machine. But I have installed 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 presently. My problem is, once the battery is fully charged and start using Ubuntu it gets drained completely within less than two hours. The interesting fact is that, I don't run any heavy tasks during this time. Watching a movie or surfing Internet causing such quick battery drain.

I have Windows also in my machine on which i get almost three and a half hours of battery backup. Can someone help me? Is this normal with Ubuntu? Or is it because of the installation of 32 bit OS on 64 bit machine?

Comment: It's not normal maybe something with you baterry charger???

Comment: You might wanna try this: [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](http://askubuntu.com/q/400/36315)

Comment: I don't know it's ubuntu specific, I've use most of Linux based distro. In my experience, they're not battery efficient as Windows is. BTW I've acer laptop.

Answer (score 3):

install TLP Battery saving tool  :- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

After installation type :-

```
sudo tlp start
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the tool. But I am specifically looking for the issue regarding this, whether its a bug in Ubuntu or my laptop issue.

Comment: TLP extended the battery life in my Dell laptop greatly - it appears that out-of-the-box Linux does not make a great attempt at power savings modes.

Answer (score -3):

Since, your machine is of 64bit, it would be better to install a 64bit OS. I am not saying that a 32bit OS can not run in a 64bit machine rather if you install 64bit OS, there will be a lesser amount of battery consumption. Plus since you are using two OS s simultaneously, the drainage of battery would obviously be higher.

Comment: I am not using two OS simultaneously, I have separate partitions for each.

Comment: I mean to say you are using both in the SAME MACHINE.

Comment: How come using two OS on different partitions causes a battery drainage? Then why doesn't it affect my Windows partition?

Comment: @Anandu M Das, It doesn't. Neither does running a 32bit OS on a 64bit processor.

Comment: @KUNJESHKUMARMISHRA You might want to back up some of your claims.

Comment: @KUNJESHKUMARMISHRA btw, you can edit your answer if you realise you misspoke or could improve it somehow.