# Power management and overheating

Tags: power-management, hp, battery, overheating, sensors

I have a HP envy 14. And dual booting windows 8 and Linux ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is that it sometimes gets a little hotter than when booted with windows. 
Also I see that Linux "eats" the power. Laptop can't cope with that hunger. Even in power cord it cannot fully charge when Linux is on.

Is there any power management tool and something that works like "coolsense"? Sensors don't work I guess. And even if they work the management by default is poor.
I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try tlp. http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tlp-0-5-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1012-1012-04-linux-mint-17161413-and-elementary-os-0-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `indicator-cpufreq` software might help, to some extent at least.

See http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/control-your-cpu-speed-from-the-ubuntu-indicator-applet/ on how to install it.

If you are patient( unlike me), you can take the whole walk-through the whole/detailed power management configuration procedure: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

Also relevant: [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've had those overheating issues when I tried for first time Ubuntu. I'm not an expert but I'll share how I solved my problem. I have AMD processor and ati radeon 76xx HD video card btw.

First I've installed fglrx drivers. You can easily find with a "how can I install proprietary drivers for Linux NVIDIA/ATI". That helped much, I couldn't even get 4 hours of battery life with windows now I have 6 hours of battery life and 38-40 degrees temperature in easy tasks.

Secondly, you may want to try "tlp power management tool". I can't give the exact pathway to how, I'm writing from phone sorry:). That also helped, lowers 1-2 degrees average but increases battery life.

You may want to check other Linux websites, but I'm pretty sure that will work.