# Battery drains very fast on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, battery, nvidia-optimus

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 Laptop with dual boot between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The battery lasts for about 6 hours on Windows but lasts only 2.5 hrs or less on Ubuntu. Since the difference is substantial, it doesn't seem normal to me.

I think it is some driver issue but I don't know how to solve it. I've already read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks) post but it didn't help.
Any suggestions?

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380d
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380d
```

Comment: Pleas [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @pilot6: Ok! Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have hybrid graphics. Both adapters are powered all the time and that is way battery life is low. Nvidia adapter is new. So you need to install drivers. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot.

If the driver installs OK, you will be able to switch Intel and Nvidia adapters in Nvidia Settings program. And power consumption must be much lower in Intel.

In your current state Nvidia adapter is always powered but not used by the system because opensource driver does not support it. So it is just waste of power.

Comment: On the first command it says `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
`

Comment: @ARBY Are you connected to internet? The command is correct.

Comment: Yes, I am.. However I am on a proxy server of my college. upgrade command is working.

Comment: That's probably a proxy problem.

Comment: @ARBY And did the solution work for you or not?

Comment: I'm waiting yet to see how long it lasts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25974/discussion-between-pilot6-and-arby).