# Dell Inpsiron 15 running Ubuntu 15 runs hot and battery drains fast

Tags: power-management, battery, overheating

My laptop runs at around 55 degrees (Fahrenheit) after its been left idle, upon startup its only about 38. On Windows 10, it's only up to about 45 degrees at max. My battery life used to be about 3-5 hours on Windows, but now I have only about an hour if I'm being careful. I have read that it's a power management problem with Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how to fix this or an add on that will solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows defaults to some sort of "balanced" power plan. You may be running performance in Ubuntu.

You might try indicator-cpufreq package which is available for Ubuntu 15.04 here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/indicator-cpufreq and for 15.10 here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/indicator-cpufreq.

You may also find [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks) helpful.

Comment: Its a fresh installation of Ubuntu, so I wouldn't be surprised if its on performance. Were would I find the option to change that, or command for that matter.

Comment: "You might try indicator-cpufreq package which is available for Ubuntu 15"