# My battery started draining very fast ,but only when I use Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dell, battery, inspiron

I am using a Laptop Dell 15 5555. 
What can i do.

> CPU~Quad core AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G (-MCP-) speed/max~1300/1800 MHz Kernel~4.10.0-33-generic x86_64 Up~4 min Mem~1048.2/11518.6MB HDD~1000.2GB(2.5% used) Procs~225 Client~Shell inxi~2.2.35

Comment: It runs an AMD APU so you *may* try the AMD proprietary drivers.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks

Comment: @MichaelBay How I know if I am use AMD proprietary drivers

Comment: Simple, if you don't know you don't have them because it must be installed by the user. The default is `radeon` or `amdgpu`, both open source.

Answer (score -1):

Just install **TLP Power Management** on your ubuntu. Like my laptop before installed TLP , the battery drain very fast.
to install it, open your terminal and type :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp

after that run this command :

> sudo apt-get update

after update, install the TLP using this command :

> sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw

to start the TLP, run this command :

> sudo tlp start

to show the status, run this command :

> sudo tlp stat

hope it will work for you, because it works for me.