# The Thinkpad T480 boasts 30 hours of battery life, I'm getting 6

Tags: 18.04, battery, thinkpad

What gives? How come Ubuntu chews through both of my two batteries so fast?

Using 18.04.1 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Ubuntu is hardware-agnostic and you need to [set the battery savings yourself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks) for your particular hardware.