# Battery draining too fast

Tags: 20.04, battery

I have started using ubuntu and battery draining is too fast as compared to windows. I heard about TLP but it doesn't seem to help.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 as Asus Vivibook F571 with NVIDIA GTX 1650. I have installed proprietary graphic driver still I am facing the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open NVIDIA X Server settings -> PRIME PROFILE -> Select "INTEL (Power saving mode)
2. Restart the device
3. Verify by Opening settings -> About -> Graphics

or

1. Disable the NVIDIA driver using `sudo prime-select intel`
2. Restart the device
3. Verify which drivers are being used `prime-select query`

Comment: @Shah Keep in mind you may want to do the reverse for running software that uses the graphics intensely. So your next question better not be "I'm playing game X and it runs badly" ;)